# Conexión con la base de datos desde un archivo jsp

Tags: java, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, jsp

Estoy intentando crear algo parecido a un login que guarde los datos de unos clientes en una base de datos en phpmyadmin con MAMP, el caso es que no me introduce los valores en la BDD podria ser que no esté referenciando bien la base de datos?  es el siguiente:

- Creo el formulario con sus respectivos nombres que quiero guardar
- Los guardo en sus variables
- Hago la conexión con la base de datos creada
- Especifico los errores que me puede dar la base de datos

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>   
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Bienvenido cliente !</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="clientes.jsp" method="post">

<label for="selectname"> Introduce tu nombre</label>
<input type="text" name= "username" required><br>
<label for="selectpassword"> Introduce contraseña</label>
<input type="password" name= "password" required><br>
<label for="selectcountry">Introduce país</label>
<select name="country">
<option value="Spain">Spain</option> 
<option value="US">US</option>
</select><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 

</form>


<%!


class client
{
    
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    
    public client(String username,String password,String country){
        
        
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        this.country=country;           
        
    }
    
    public boolean insertClientRecord(){
        
        //establecemos la conexión con la BDD
        
        dbmsConnection connect= null;
        Connection con= null;
        PreparedStatement stmt= null;
        boolean insert=false;
        try{
            connect= new dbmsConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/vit","root","");
            con = connect.getConnection();
            String sql = "Insert into client values (?,?,?);";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, password);
            stmt.setString(3, country);
            int i= stmt.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
                
                insert=true;
            }else{
                
                insert=false;
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            
        }
            return insert;
    }
    class dbmsConnection{
        
        String url;
        String password;
        String username;
        
        public dbmsConnection(String url,String username,String password){
            
            this.url=url;
            this.username=username;
            this.password=password;
            
        }
        public Connection getConnection(){
        
            Connection con=null;
            
            try{
                
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                
            }
            return con;
        }
        
        public void closeConnection(Statement stmt,Connection con) throws SQLException{
            
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            
        }
        
    }
    
}




%>




<%

String sub = request.getParameter("submit");
if (sub!=null){
    
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String country = request.getParameter("country");
    try{
        
        client c = new client(username,password,country);
        boolean result=c.insertClientRecord();
        if(result){
            
            out.print("Record Inserted Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            out.print("nadaaa");
        }
        
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        
        
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        
    }
    
    //out.println("Bienvenido "+username);
}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

alguna ayuda ? el mesnaje de error es:

Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "con" is null
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Esta es la base de datos que he creado con MAMP phpmyadmin.

Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Habría que ver qué hace `connect.getConnection();`, puesto que te está devolviendo un `null` cuando tú esperas que devuelva otra cosa. Sin verlo, es complicado saber qué pasa

Comment: Revisa la clase dbmsConnection, porque debes de tener un error en el método getConnection() ve si el try-catch esta capturando una excepción.